# How to extrapolate variables to make them become globals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, global-variables

Let's say I have to find out the window width, the code will be:

```
$(window).width();
```

and if I want it to become a global variable i just have to declare its name:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
```

The result will be the window's width.
But I need that variable to change when things happens, for example when I resize the window:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
});
```

How can I extrapolate this variable in order to override the one before?
I can override the variable before putting the function i need in the .resize(function(); but in this way my code confusionary and I need just a variable to use it in other functions outside the resize function, for example a .click(function)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();

        //click function goes here.
    });
});
```

how if I want that the function above will become a whole new variable? without putting a new function in it?

Comment: remove the `var` in the resize? `var` is used to declare a variable, if you just want to update it's value, don't use `var`

Comment: The fact is that I need firstly the variable when the document is ready and when the window is resized I need that variable to change. If I delete the first variable, I don't get any content.

try the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dcdeiv/xZUtD/4/
and resize the window. The ... will change into a number, the last one will change according the resize, but will begin with the first one that will always be the same.

Comment: not sure what you mean as I never mention the deletion of the first variable

Answer (score 3):

the problem with your code is that you have var twice. every time you use var you create a new variable. so just leave out the second one like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        w = $(window).width();

        //click function goes here.
    });
});
```

Comment: The fact is that I need firstly the variable when the document is ready and when the window is resized I need that variable to change. If I delete the first variable, I don't get any content.

try the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dcdeiv/xZUtD/4/

and resize the window. The ... will change into a number, the last one will change according the resize, but will begin with the first one that will always be the same.

Comment: are you talking about 2 different width variables? if so then use 2 variables, 1 to stay as constant and 1 that changes http://jsfiddle.net/xZUtD/5/

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar for my projects:

```
var winWidth, winHeight;

function setWinSize(){
    winWidth = $(window).width();
    winHeight = $(window).height();
    //note I'm not using the var suffix again
}

//then we set the new values on document ready and on window resize
$(document).ready(function(){
    setWinSize();
})
$(window).resize(function(){
    setWinSize();
})

function myCustomFunction(){
    //I can now use my vars here
}
```

Comment: here's a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9j2Bv/
you should include jquery, dont't wrap the js in $(document).ready(), and call the myCustomFunction() after declaring it

Comment: still not working! when I resize the window I get the same results!